Tips on writing a transgender character?
I have a transgender oc, Rocky, born Rochelle. He's like eight. He doesn't know anything about LGBTQ+ people or that his twin sister Rosamie (Rosie) is a lesbian and has her own struggles and will totally accept him or that his father figure/random manipulative guy who raised them and some other random kids because of their shape-shifting abilities is homophobic and transphobic. However, a very important scene is when Rocky tells Rosie that he thinks he's a boy. Any tips from trans people on how to go about that?
Just to clarify Rocky is female to male. Thank you!

I recommend that you go to https://www.reddit.com/r/trans/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/asktransgender/ and search the sites and read the posts that are relevant to your question before you ask a question and then, if your question hasn't been answered, ask a question there.

@Ben Do not tell people to try another site, and ask questions on another site. If you know the answer, answer it. If you don't, don't answer it. This site exists to answer questions from aspiring writers, do not discourage them from asking valid questions here. This is a valid question; and you are a citizen here, not a director.

"He's like eight"? Do you mean that he's about eight years old?

I would suggest you create a scene, an unusual first time scene for the twins, in which they are alone and happen to reveal such preferences.
For eight year olds, this might be watching a kid's movie, and when they play act, Roxanne wants to be the male lead, the prince, the swashbuckler, that saves the princess.
But this is the third time Rocky always wants to be the male lead, and Rosie notices that, and says so.

"Why do you always want to be the man?"
Rocky looks confused. "When I grow up, I'll be the man."
Rosie looks concerned. "Okay. But don't ever tell Daddy that."
"Why?"
"He is very mean to girls that don't want to be girls. He will hit you."

Use your own words, make up your own scene. But this way the information comes out "organically", it isn't a big reveal, it is just Rosie's powers of observation, and no communication barriers between 8 year old twins.
Good luck.
